# Url rewrites not working after upgrading Magento version

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite

So I updated my site to 1.6 version of Magento and then I backtracked back to 1.5. My site has a bunch of Url rewrites but now they seem not to be working and will take me to an a cannot be found page. Can anyone help?

Getting this in terminal now after doing what was suggested below and trying to reindex.

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex all
Product Attributes index was rebuilt successfully
Product Prices index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'date' in 'field list'' in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(337): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1544): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1494): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertArray('catalog_product...', Array, Array)
#7 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price.php(530): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertMultiple('catalog_product...', Array)
#8 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price.php(371): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price->_prepareWebsiteDateTable()
#9 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(125): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#10 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(139): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#11 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(167): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#14 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'date' in 'field list'' in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#3 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(337): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1544): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1494): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertArray('catalog_product...', Array, Array)
#6 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price.php(530): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertMultiple('catalog_product...', Array)
#7 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price.php(371): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price->_prepareWebsiteDateTable()
#8 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(125): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(139): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(167): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#13 {main}
Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully
Product Flat Data index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'created_at'' in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#4 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(337): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#5 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(652): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#6 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(122): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable('1')
#7 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(115): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Flat_Indexer->rebuild('1')
#8 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(64): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Flat_Indexer->rebuild(NULL)
#9 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(301): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->rebuild()
#10 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(139): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#11 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(167): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#14 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'created_at'' in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#3 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(337): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#4 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(652): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#5 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(122): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable('1')
#6 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(115): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Flat_Indexer->rebuild('1')
#7 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(64): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Flat_Indexer->rebuild(NULL)
#8 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(301): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->rebuild()
#9 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(139): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#10 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(167): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#13 {main}
Category Flat Data index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
`updated_at` ,
`path` varchar(255) not null,
`position` int(11) not null defaul' at line 4' in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#4 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(337): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#5 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Category/Flat.php(526): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('CREATE TABLE `c...')
#6 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Category/Flat.php(433): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Flat->_createTable('1')
#7 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Indexer/Flat.php(237): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Flat->rebuild()
#8 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(139): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#9 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(167): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#10 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#11 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#12 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
`updated_at` ,
`path` varchar(255) not null,
`position` int(11) not null defaul' at line 4' in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#3 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(337): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#4 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Category/Flat.php(526): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('CREATE TABLE `c...')
#5 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Category/Flat.php(433): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Flat->_createTable('1')
#6 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Indexer/Flat.php(237): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Flat->rebuild()
#7 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(139): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#8 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(167): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#9 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#10 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#11 {main}
Category Products index was rebuilt successfully
Catalog Search Index index was rebuilt successfully
Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully
Tag Aggregation Data index was rebuilt successfully
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to your MySQL or phpMyAdmin, you can truncate the table called **core_url_rewrite**. After that you can start running a new index for url rewrites.

You can run this SQL query in phpMyAdmin(remember to select your database):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `core_url_rewrite`;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

After you have truncated the table you can index via Magento backend or

do it in Terminal / SSH with this code from the Magento root folder:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but that did not work.

Comment: Actually updated my question, tried to reindex and got these errors above.

Comment: Maybe you should just replace the files with the originals?